# How to add property to object using typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have objects that i parsed to build final object , so i tried to add `tempObject1` and `tempObject2` to `OrderRequest` but it is not adding to object. So i have mentioned how i want output after processing.

index.ts

```
export class OrderRequest {
private containingJSON = {"OrderRequest": {}};;
    public rxOrderRequest(_request: any): OrderRequest {

                const tempObject1: object = Object.assign({}, JSON.parse(strInfo));

                const tempObject2: object = Object.assign({}, JSON.parse(strNonType),
                    JSON.parse(strType)
                );
                this.containingJSON['OrderRequest'] = tempObject1;
                this.containingJSON['OrderRequest']= tempObject2


                return this;
            }
}
```

output

```
"OrderRequest": {
        User:{},
        Order: {nonCrittical:Object,critical:object}
}
```

Comment: Your expected object is not valid. You can either have array of objects or just an object with key/value pairs.

Comment: i have updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're re-assigning this.containingJSON['OrderRequest'] in your code, instead of creating new properties.
Based on how you want, following is the updated code

```
export class OrderRequest {
private containingJSON = {"OrderRequest": {}};;
    public rxOrderRequest(_request: any): OrderRequest {

                const tempObject1: object = Object.assign({}, JSON.parse(strInfo));

                const tempObject2: object = Object.assign({}, JSON.parse(strNonType),
                    JSON.parse(strType)
                );
                this.containingJSON['OrderRequest']['tempObject1'] = tempObject1;// assign tempObject1 to a new property "tempObject1"
                this.containingJSON['OrderRequest']['tempObject2'] = tempObject2;


                return this;
            }
}
```

Comment: its printing this `{ tempObject1: { User: [Object] },
     tempObject2: { nonCritical: [Object], critical: [Object] } } }
`

Comment: but i want `{  User: [Object] }, Order: {nonCritical: [Object], critical: [Object] } }`

Comment: In your question you mentioned that you wanted something with keys like this : "OrderRequest": {
        tempObject1:{},
        tempObject2: {}
} 
Now, I'm not sure if you want an object/ array of objects or anything else.
This : { User: [Object] }, Order: {nonCritical: [Object], critical: [Object] } } is again not a valid single javascript object

Comment: can you show how strInfo and strNonType look like before parsing ?

Comment: i added strInfo problem is with User , Order is coming correct